# What is the spiritual significance of Laxmi Devi?

Tags: laxmi

Spirituality generally refers to the immortality of the soul and the impermanence of material needs. But if it is so , then what is the spiritual significance of Laxmi Devi , as she primarity bestow wealth and money to her devotees ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstanding, if I say mahadev only destroys the world, what's need to worship him?

In this statement I am ignoring that mahadev also give boons , moksha, health, life and everything.

So,you are just ignoring other things devi can do.

Quoting from devi [Lakshmi strotam](https://www.hinduismabout.com/2015/06/lakshmi-stotram-or-mahalakshmi-stotram.html?m=1)

> सर्वज्ञे सर्ववरदे सर्वदुष्टभयङ्करि ।
>
> सर्वदुःखहरे देवि महालक्ष्मि नमोऽस्तु ते ॥3॥
>
> O ! Goddess Mahalakshmi,who is known to all,you are the one who
> ***gives boons to her devotees,A remover of all the sins,who destroys fear and diseases*** and O ! Mahalakshmi I always worship you.
>
> सिद्धिबुद्धिप्रदे देवि भुक्तिमुक्तिप्रदायिनि ।
>
> मन्त्रपूते सदा देवि महालक्ष्मि नमोऽस्तु ते ॥4॥
>
> O  ! Goddess,you are the ***one who gives intelligence and success to
> the people in need and you give enjoyment and liberation,***

Quoting from lakshmi tantra chapter 6

> Sakra: — O Goddess, who appearest from the milky ocean, wife of the
> God Padmanabha, I prostrate myself before Thee, who art lotus-born.
> Deign to explain who a living being is. Sri: — The primordial,
> absolute I-hood of Hari is myself and I am the transcendental, supreme
> Goddess

.

Comment: Thank you very much @Hope for the answer. I needed this answer.